# How to gather rows from a matrix by indices list using CUDA Thrust

Tags: cuda, thrust

This is seemingly a simple problem but I just can’t figure out an elegant way to do this with CUDA Thrust.

I have a two dimensional matrix NxM and a vector of desired row indices of size L  that is a subset of all rows(i.e. L < N)  and is not regular (basically an irregular list like, 7,11,13,205,... etc.). The matrix is stored by rows in a thrust device vector. The array of indices is a device vector as well. 
Here are my two questions:

1. What is the most efficient way to copy the desired rows from the original NxM matrix forming a new matrix LxM?
2. Is it possible to create an iterator for the original NxM matrix that would dereference to only elements that belong to the desired rows?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Do the indices correspond to the rows of the matrix? And is the memory pitch of the matrix M words?

Comment: talonmies, Thank you for your reply. Not sure what you mean by “correspond” but the indices are row index of the matrix. So that for MxN matrix a value in the indices array is always in the interval [0,M) and all values are sequential and unique but not contiguous.  So for example, for 100x1000 matrix the values could be [3,17,18,37,38,39,97].
I am not sure how to answer the pitch question either  but, the matrix is stored by rows i.e. a(0,0),..a(0,N-1),a(1,0), …, a(1,n-1), … a(M-1,0),…,a(M-1,N-1). The data element type is cuComplex which is float2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking about seems like a pretty straight forward stream compaction problem, and there isn't any particular problem doing it with thrust, but there are a couple of twists. In order to select the rows to copy, you need to have an stencil or key that the stream compaction algorithm can use. That needs to be constructed by a search or select operation using your list of rows to copy.

One example procedure to do this would go something like this:

1. Construct an iterator which returns the row number of any entry in the input matrix. Thrust has a very useful `counting_iterator` and `transform_iterator` which can be combined to do this
2. Perform a search of that row number iterator to find which entries match the list of rows to copy. `thrust::binary search` can be used for this. The search yields the stencil for the stream compaction operation
3. Use `thrust::copy_if` to perform the stream compaction on the input matrix with the stencil.

It sounds like a lot of work and intermediate steps, but the counting and transformation iterators don't actually produce any intermediate device vectors. The only intermediate storage required is the stencil array, which can be a boolean (so m*n bytes).

A full example in code:

```
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/binary_search.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <cstdio>

struct div_functor : public thrust::unary_function<int,int>
{
    int m;
    div_functor(int _m) : m(_m) {};

    __host__ __device__
    int operator()(int x) const
    {
        return x / m;
    }
};

struct is_true
{
    __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(bool x) { return x; }
};


int main(void)
{

    // dimensions of the problem
    const int m=20, n=5, l=4;

    // Counting iterator for generating sequential indices

    // Sample matrix containing 0...(m*n)
    thrust::counting_iterator<float> indices(0.f);
    thrust::device_vector<float> in_matrix(m*n);
    thrust::copy(indices, indices+(m*n), in_matrix.begin());

    // device vector contain rows to select
    thrust::device_vector<int> select(l);
    select[0] = 1;
    select[1] = 4;
    select[2] = 9;
    select[3] = 16;

    // construct device iterator supplying row numbers via a functor
    typedef thrust::counting_iterator<int> counter;
    typedef thrust::transform_iterator<div_functor, counter> rowIterator;
    rowIterator rows_begin = thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0), div_functor(n));
    rowIterator rows_end = rows_begin + (m*n);

    // constructor a stencil array which indicates which entries will be copied
    thrust::device_vector<bool> docopy(m*n);
    thrust::binary_search(select.begin(), select.end(), rows_begin, rows_end, docopy.begin());

    // use stream compaction on the matrix with the stencil array
    thrust::device_vector<float> out_matrix(l*n);
    thrust::copy_if(in_matrix.begin(), in_matrix.end(), docopy.begin(), out_matrix.begin(), is_true());

    for(int i=0; i<(l*n); i++) {
        float val = out_matrix[i];
        printf("%i %f\n", i, val);
    }
}
```

(usual disclaimer: use at your own risk)

About the only comment I would make is that the predicate to the `copy_if` call feels a bit redundant given we have already a binary stencil that could be used directly, but there doesn't seem to be a variant of the compaction algorithms which can operate on a binary stencil directly. Similarly, I could not think of a sensible way to use the list of rows directly in the stream compaction call. There might well be a more efficient way to do this with thrust, but this should at least get you started.

---

From your comment, it seems that space is tight and the additional memory overhead of the binary search and stencil creation is prohibitive for your application. In that case I would follow the advice I offered in a comment to Roger Dahl's answer, and use a custom copy kernel instead. Thrust device vectors can be cast to a pointer you can pass directly to a kernel (`thrust::raw_pointer_cast`), so it need not interfere with your existing thrust code. I would suggest using a block of threads per row to copy, that allows coalescing of reads and writes and should perform a lot better than using `thrust::copy` for each row. A *very* simple implementation might look something like this (reusing most of my thrust example):

```
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <cstdio>

__global__ 
void rowcopykernel(const float *in, float *out, const int *list, const int m, const int n, const int l)
{
    __shared__ const float * inrowp; 
    __shared__ float * outrowp;

    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        inrowp = (blockIdx.x < l) ? in + (n*list[blockIdx.x]) : 0;
        outrowp = out + (n*blockIdx.x);
    }
    __syncthreads();

    for(int i=threadIdx.x; (inrowp != 0) && (i<n); i+=blockDim.x) {
        *(outrowp+i) = *(inrowp+i);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    // dimensions of the problem
    const int m=20, n=5, l=4;

    // Sample matrix containing 0...(m*n)
    thrust::counting_iterator<float> indices(0.f);
    thrust::device_vector<float> in_matrix(m*n);
    thrust::copy(indices, indices+(m*n), in_matrix.begin());

    // device vector contain rows to select
    thrust::device_vector<int> select(l);
    select[0] = 1;
    select[1] = 4;
    select[2] = 9;
    select[3] = 16;

    // Output matrix
    thrust::device_vector<float> out_matrix(l*n);

    // raw pointer to thrust vectors
    int * selp = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&select[0]);
    float * inp = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&in_matrix[0]);
    float * outp = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&out_matrix[0]);

    dim3 blockdim = dim3(128);
    dim3 griddim = dim3(l);
    rowcopykernel<<<griddim,blockdim>>>(inp, outp, selp, m, n, l);

    for(int i=0; i<(l*n); i++) {
        float val = out_matrix[i];
        printf("%i %f\n", i, val);
    }
}
```

(standard disclaimer: use at your own risk).

The execution parameter selection could be made fancier, but otherwise that should be about all that is required. If your rows are very small, you might want to investigate using a *warp* per row rather than a block (so one block copies several rows). If you have more than 65535 output rows, then you will need to either use a 2D grid, or modify the code to have each block do multiple rows. But, as with the thrust based solution about, this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to come up with this solution. You did answer my question, but unfortunately I could not use this approach in my application because the additional allocation of memory made it run out of GPU resources.  Because of that, I couldn’t verify whether the performance in my specific case will be better than a simple row by row copy with thrust:: copy() that I am using now.  I suspect that it may not be because the creation of the stencil array alone seem to performs many more operations  plus doubles the memory usage.

Comment: The performance of a simple copy is not too terrible on my machine - about 1ms for a 84Kx132 matrix with 55 desired indices. I will wait for a few more days before accepting  your answer in hope that someone else might come with another solution that would be possible for me to use in my application. Thanks again!

Comment: @Leo: please have a look at the second solution in my edit. You might be able to build something off it that will out perform your multiple `thrust::copy` calls.

Comment: It's been 6+ years since this answer was written - is there a more efficient way now? I'm using the Thrust method right now but on a very large matrix it's become the bottleneck. (I can create a separate question about it if you feel necessary)

Answer (score 1):

if you are not fixed on thrust, check out [Arrafire](http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/c/):

surprisingly unlike thrust, this library has a native support for subscript indexing,
so that your problem can be solved in just few lines of code:

```
const int N = 7, M = 5;

float L_host[] = {3, 6, 4, 1}; 
int szL = sizeof(L_host) / sizeof(float); 

// generate random NxM matrix with cuComplex data 
array A = randu(N, M, c32); 
// array used to index rows
array L(szL, 1, L_host);

print(A);
print(L);

array B = A(L,span); // copy selected rows of A
print(B);
```

and the results:

```
A =
       0.7402 +       0.9210i       0.6814 +       0.2920i       0.5786 +       0.5538i       0.2133 +       0.4131i       0.7305 +       0.9400i
       0.0390 +       0.9690i       0.3194 +       0.8109i       0.3557 +       0.7229i       0.0328 +       0.5360i       0.8432 +       0.6116i
       0.9251 +       0.4464i       0.1541 +       0.4452i       0.2783 +       0.6192i       0.7214 +       0.3546i       0.2674 +       0.0208i
       0.6673 +       0.1099i       0.2080 +       0.6110i       0.5876 +       0.3750i       0.2527 +       0.9847i       0.8331 +       0.7218i
       0.4702 +       0.5132i       0.3073 +       0.4156i       0.2405 +       0.4148i       0.9200 +       0.1872i       0.6087 +       0.6301i
       0.7762 +       0.2948i       0.2343 +       0.8793i       0.0937 +       0.6326i       0.1820 +       0.5984i       0.5298 +       0.8127i
       0.7140 +       0.3585i       0.6462 +       0.9264i       0.2849 +       0.7793i       0.7082 +       0.0421i       0.0593 +       0.4797i


L = (row indices)
       3.0000 
       6.0000 
       4.0000 
       1.0000




B =
       0.6673 +       0.1099i       0.2080 +       0.6110i       0.5876 +       0.3750i       0.2527 +       0.9847i       0.8331 +       0.7218i
       0.7140 +       0.3585i       0.6462 +       0.9264i       0.2849 +       0.7793i       0.7082 +       0.0421i       0.0593 +       0.4797i
       0.4702 +       0.5132i       0.3073 +       0.4156i       0.2405 +       0.4148i       0.9200 +       0.1872i       0.6087 +       0.6301i
       0.0390 +       0.9690i       0.3194 +       0.8109i       0.3557 +       0.7229i       0.0328 +       0.5360i       0.8432 +       0.6116i
```

it also works pretty fast. I tested this with an array of cuComplex of size
2000 x 2000 using the following code:

```
float *g_data = 0, *g_data2 = 0;
int g_N = 2000, g_M = 2000, // matrix of size g_N x g_M
       g_L = 400;          // copy g_L rows
void af_test() 
{   
  array A(g_N, g_M, (cuComplex *)g_data, afDevicePointer);
  array L(g_L, 1, g_data2, afDevicePointer);
  array B = (A(L, span));
  std::cout << "sz: " << B.elements() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
   // input matrix N x M of cuComplex
   array in = randu(g_N, g_M, c32);
   g_data = (float *)in.device< cuComplex >();
   // generate unique row indices
   array in2 = setunique(floor(randu(g_L) * g_N));
   print(in2);
   g_data2 = in2.device<float>();

   const int N_ITERS = 30;
   try {
     info();
     af::sync();
     timer::tic();

     for(int i = 0; i < N_ITERS; i++) {
       af_test();      
     }
     af::sync();
     printf("af:  %.5f seconds\n",  timer::toc() / N_ITERS);


   } catch (af::exception& e) {
     fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e.what());
  }
  in.unlock();
  in2.unlock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this with Thrust but, because the operation will be memory bound, it should be easy to write a kernel that performs this operation at maximum possible performance. Simply create the same number of threads as there are indices in the vector. Have each thread calculate the source and destination addresses for one row and then use `memcpy()` to copy the row.

You may also want to carefully consider if it is possible to set up subsequent processing steps to access the rows in place, thereby avoiding the entire, expensive "compacting" operation, that only shuffles memory around. Even if addressing the rows becomes slightly more complicated (an extra memory lookup and multiply, maybe), overall performance may be much better.

Comment: I would probably launch a warp or even block for each index and have the group of threads perform the memory copy of a given row. There is much better chance of coalescing reads and writes that using threadwise `memcpy`.

Comment: @talonmies: Thanks for the info. I found another SO answer that you had given that lists the PTX generated for `memcpy()` and it is indeed extremely simplistic. But I think it might still run with good performance, at least on Fermi, because of the L1 cache. Even if the cache doesn't help, there is still a chance that the PTX compiler detects the byte copy pattern and optimizes it, but maybe that is unlikely.